# jQuery auto detect if I need to use .html() or .val()

Tags: jquery

I am writting a jquery plugin to create ajax calls designed for my app.

Inside this plugin, my ajax call looks like this (reduced to what the question need) :

```
    $.ajax({
        url: route,
        type: "post",
        data: inputData,
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (outputSelector !== undefined) {

                $(outputSelector).html(response);
                // or
                $(outputSelector).val(response);

            }
        }
    });
```

outputSelector is a selector, defined outside the plugin. I do not know if this selector is a `<div>` or an `<input>` or even a `<select>`. Is there a smart way to know if I need to use val(), or html() ?

Comment: Can your selector be an arbitrary one, e.g. `"div, input, select"`?

Comment: which is the structure of the response you get? can you give us an example?

Comment: the responses are only strings (no json or such)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Possibly we could check if the element has `value` property:

```
var el = $(outputSelector);
if (el[0].value !== undefined) {
    el.val(response);
} else {
    el.html(response);
}
```

So, somewhat like one line universal solution could be:

```
$(outputSelector).each(function() {
    this[this.value !== undefined ? "value" : "innerHTML"] = response;
});
```

Comment: this solution would be easier to maintain, then potentially updating switch statments or `.is()` selectors down the road.  Only thing to note, is if you can potentially have a selector which Álvaro mentions in comments (`"div, input, select"`) you may need to `.split()` on the comma and check each element individually.

Comment: Your way is working very well, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCCsD/). Thank you. In a `$.each()` I'll be able to handle multiple selections.

Comment: @Ninsuo In case of many output elements, you may use `$(outputSelector).each(function() { if (this.value !== undefined) { ... } });`, just as [xdazz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12919512/1249581) proposed.

Answer (score 4):

If the `outputSelector` is a class selector, and the elements is mixed types, you need to use `.each`.
Although it's not good to mix `div` and `input` with same class, but if you are creating a plugin, you need to consider such case.

```
$(outputSelector).each(function() {
    if ('value' in this) {
        $(this).val(response);
    } else {
        $(this).html(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.is(..)` method to determine which method to use.

```
$.ajax({
    url: route,
    type: "post",
    data: inputData,
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (outputSelector !== undefined) {
            var $output = $(outputSelector),
                method = $output.is('input,select,textarea') ? 'val' : 'html';

            $output[method](response);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to determine if a property is defined for a given selector:

```
if ($(outputSelector).prop("value") !== undefined)
  $(outputSelector).val(response);
else
  $(outputSelector).html(response);
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/73nf8/)**

alternatively you could us [.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your success function, put:

```
if (outputSelector !== undefined) {
    if(outputSelector.is("input"))
    {
        outputSelector.val(response);
    } 
    else if (outputSelector.is("div"))
    {
        outputSelector.html(response);
    }
}
```

it would be better syntax to use a switch statement, but if you assume only input will be used for `val()`, and everything else is `html()` then just replace the last `else if` with just `else` and remove the conditional.